# Bootstrap 4 form with repeating rows not aligning

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to make a useful reactive form to modify settings for a greenhouse automation device.  I cannot make this look good with Bootstrap 4.  Can you offer any advice?  My main issues are:

- The form has 3 sections - general, port settings and rules (for turning ports on and off based on timers, other port triggering or environmental data like CO2 or temperature/humidity)  I tried to use panels to separate the sections but there are no borders around the panels.
- Each port can be an input or output and the settings differ based on direction.  I don't like the way this looks either in the browser or on my iphone but if I could even get it to center the elements properly it would be at least usable  (headers aren't centered, checkboxes aren't within their columns and spacing is off)

I haven't added the last section because I can't get the first 2 looking right.  Here's the code I have done so far:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="text-center"></div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h2>Device Settings</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <form id="generic" class="form-horizontal" name="generic" action="http://127.0.0.1:51709/settings/handleDevice/deviceID/3" method="post">
                <div class="form-row">
                    <label for="deviceName" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Device Name</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <input type="text" name="deviceName" class="form-control" id="deviceName" value="Shop Monitor" onchange="this.form.submit();">
                    </div>
                    <label for="deviceAbbr" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">ABBR</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <input type="text" name="deviceAbbr" class="form-control" id="deviceAbbr" value="MA" onchange="this.form.submit();">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="col-sm-2">Device Status</div>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <div class="form-check">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="bActive" id="bActive" class="form-check-input" value="1" onchange="this.form.submit();" checked="">
                            <label for="bActive" class="form-check-label">(Active)</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-row">
                    <label for="fwVersion" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Firmware Version</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10"> <input type="text" name="fwVersion" readonly="" class="form-control-plaintext" id="deviceAbbr" value="41"> </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-row">
                    <label for="configVersion" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"> Config Version </label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10"> <input type="text" name="configVersion" readonly="" class="form-control-plaintext" id="deviceAbbr" value="99"> </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-row">
                    <label for="configVersion" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"> Last Seen </label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10"> <input type="text" name="dLastSeen" readonly="" class="form-control-plaintext" style="color: green" id="deviceAbbr" value="07/12/19 07:30:01"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-row">
                    <label for="serialNumber" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"> Serial Number </label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10"> <input type="text" name="configVersion" readonly="" class="form-control-plaintext" id="deviceAbbr" value="240AC413FD24"> </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h2>Port Settings</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <form id="ports" name="ports" action="http://127.0.0.1:51709/settings/handleAirnode/deviceID/3" method="post">
                <div class="form-row text-align-center">
                    <div class="col-sm-2 text-align-center"></div>
                    <div class="col-sm-1 text-align-center">Active</div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2 text-align-center">Type</div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2 text-align-center">Port Name</div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2 text-align-center">NO/NC</div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2 text-align-center">Debounce (ms)</div>
                    <div class="col-sm-1 text-align-center">Notify?</div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-row text-align-center">
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <span class="">Port 5</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-1">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="ps_bActive_5" class="form-check-input" value="1">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <select name="ps_bInput_5" class="form-control" onchange="this.form.submit();">
                            <option value="1" selected="">INPUT</option>
                            <option value="0">OUTPUT</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <input type="text" name="ps_name_5" value="Port 5" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <select name="ps_bState_5" class="form-control">
                            <option value="1">Normally Closed</option>
                            <option value="0" selected="">Normally Open</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <input type="text" name="ps_debounce_5" value="200" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-1">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="ps_bNotify_5" class="form-check-input" value="1">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-row text-align-center">
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <span class="">Port 6</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-1">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="ps_bActive_6" class="form-check-input" value="1">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <select name="ps_bInput_6" class="form-control" onchange="this.form.submit();">
                            <option value="1" selected="">INPUT</option>
                            <option value="0">OUTPUT</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <input type="text" name="ps_name_6" value="Port 6" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <select name="ps_bState_6" class="form-control">
                            <option value="1">Normally Closed</option>
                            <option value="0" selected="">Normally Open</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <input type="text" name="ps_debounce_6" value="200" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-1">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="ps_bNotify_6" class="form-check-input" value="1">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-row text-align-center">
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <span class="">Port 7</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-1">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="ps_bActive_7" class="form-check-input" value="1">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <select name="ps_bInput_7" class="form-control" onchange="this.form.submit();">
                            <option value="1" selected="">INPUT</option>
                            <option value="0">OUTPUT</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <input type="text" name="ps_name_7" value="Port 7" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <select name="ps_bState_7" class="form-control">
                            <option value="1">Normally Closed</option>
                            <option value="0" selected="">Normally Open</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <input type="text" name="ps_debounce_7" value="200" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-1">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="ps_bNotify_7" class="form-check-input" value="1">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-row text-align-center">
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <span class="">Port 8</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-1">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="ps_bActive_8" class="form-check-input" value="1" checked="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <select name="ps_bInput_8" class="form-control" onchange="this.form.submit();">
                            <option value="1" selected="">INPUT</option>
                            <option value="0">OUTPUT</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <input type="text" name="ps_name_8" value="PIR" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <select name="ps_bState_8" class="form-control">
                            <option value="1">Normally Closed</option>
                            <option value="0" selected="">Normally Open</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <input type="text" name="ps_debounce_8" value="200" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-1">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="ps_bNotify_8" class="form-check-input" value="1">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-row text-align-center">
                    <div class="col-sm-2 text-align-center"></div>
                    <div class="col-sm-1 text-align-center">Active</div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2 text-align-center">Type</div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2 text-align-center">Port Name</div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2 text-align-center"></div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2 text-align-center">Timeout (sec)</div>
                    <div class="col-sm-1 text-align-center">Allow Virtual?</div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-row text-align-center">
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <span class="">Port 1</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-1">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="ps_bActive_1" class="form-check-input" value="1" checked="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <select name="ps_bInput_1" class="form-control" onchange="this.form.submit();">
                            <option value="1">INPUT</option>
                            <option value="0" selected="">OUTPUT</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <input type="text" name="ps_name_1" value="CO2 Valve" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <select name="ps_bState_1" class="form-control">
                            <option value="1" selected="">Normally Closed</option>
                            <option value="0">Normally Open</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <input type="text" name="ps_timeout_1" value="0" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-1">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="ps_bVirtual_1" class="form-check-input" value="1" checked="">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-row text-align-center">
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <span class="">Port 2</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-1">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="ps_bActive_2" class="form-check-input" value="1" checked="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <select name="ps_bInput_2" class="form-control" onchange="this.form.submit();">
                            <option value="1">INPUT</option>
                            <option value="0" selected="">OUTPUT</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <input type="text" name="ps_name_2" value="Exhaust Fan" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <select name="ps_bState_2" class="form-control">
                            <option value="1" selected="">Normally Closed</option>
                            <option value="0">Normally Open</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <input type="text" name="ps_timeout_2" value="0" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-1">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="ps_bVirtual_2" class="form-check-input" value="1" checked="">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-row text-align-center">
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <span class="">Port 3</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-1">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="ps_bActive_3" class="form-check-input" value="1" checked="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <select name="ps_bInput_3" class="form-control" onchange="this.form.submit();">
                            <option value="1">INPUT</option>
                            <option value="0" selected="">OUTPUT</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <input type="text" name="ps_name_3" value="Alert" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <select name="ps_bState_3" class="form-control">
                            <option value="1" selected="">Normally Closed</option>
                            <option value="0">Normally Open</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <input type="text" name="ps_timeout_3" value="0" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-1">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="ps_bVirtual_3" class="form-check-input" value="1" checked="">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-row text-align-center">
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <span class="">Port 4</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-1">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="ps_bActive_4" class="form-check-input" value="1" checked="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <select name="ps_bInput_4" class="form-control" onchange="this.form.submit();">
                            <option value="1">INPUT</option>
                            <option value="0" selected="">OUTPUT</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <input type="text" name="ps_name_4" value="Lights" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <select name="ps_bState_4" class="form-control">
                            <option value="1" selected="">Normally Closed</option>
                            <option value="0">Normally Open</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <input type="text" name="ps_timeout_4" value="0" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-1">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="ps_bVirtual_4" class="form-check-input" value="1" checked="">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can [view this on codeply](https://www.codeply.com/go/haSVbdYp1e) (look for the preview icon on the right side of the lower window)

Comment: Not really sure what it is you're asking for? Just to make your layout look nicer? Is there any actual bug or unexpected output or is it just that you're trying to reign in an unwieldy form?

Comment: If you follow the codeply link and look at the preview, the column "headers" aren't center aligning and the checkboxes are way off too - they don't even fall within their columns.  That's my main problem.  If you have suggestions on how to make it look better on a mobile device too that would be a bonus.  It is definitely an unwieldy form.

Comment: I see this in firefox when I poke the flex button in dev tools:  https://www.screencast.com/t/qnCQFyb55E.  Good grief that upper section is ugly :)

Comment: I would say that 'help me make this layout look nicer' is outside the scope of SO since a lot would just be opinion based. For example, for the layout you're using for Ports I would probably use a `<table>` wrapped in `.table-responsive`.  It's just too much data to squeeze in a portrait-mode mobile device and making it all collapse into `col-12` makes the whole form seem rather obnoxious on mobile.  But that's all 100% opinion-based, which is bad SO.

Comment: Yeah it is definitely obnoxious on mobile which is bad.  Bad SO or not, opinions and specifics on how to make it usable and better looking are exactly what I was looking for.  I appreciate David's answer below, which clears up the panel issue and explains why the checkboxes were hosed, and will also try responsive tables for the 2 bottom sections.   If you have thoughts on the top section I would love to hear them.

Comment: Responsive table ftw!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple issues with your code:

1. There is no `.text-align-center` class. Instead, use `.text-center`.
2. There is no `.panel`. It's been replaced by `.card` in *Bootstrap 4*.
3. The checkbox with `.form-check-input` needs to be wrapped by `.form-check` because it has absolute positioning with negative margins.

There are so many of those checkboxes hence I only fixed those on the first 2 rows.

[image]

**demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/hexrc8fv/14/